# Threading and List, how do I go through each and compare

Tags: c#, multithreading, nested-lists, keyvaluepair

I'm trying to use a threads to pull out a nested list to compare to another list, something like this

```
List<KeyPairValues<string, List<string>> mainList = new List<KeyPairValues<string, List<string>>();

// In my actual code I create these list through a loop
List<string> A = new List<string>();
A.Add("Car");
A.Add("Plain");
A.Add("Boat");

List<string> B = new List<string>();
B.Add("Flower");
B.Add("Dog");
B.Add("House");

List<string> C = new List<string>();
C.Add("Appartment");
C.Add("Plant");
C.Add("Candy");

mainList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>("unRead", A));
mainList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>("unRead", B));
mainList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>("unRead", C));

List<string> compareList = new List<string>();
compareList.Add("Car");
compareList.Add("Boat");
compareList.Add("Dog");
List<string> resList = new List<string>();
```

My first thought was to use a foreach loop to go through it, in my current code I have 32 lists in the mainList.

```
foreach(var item in mainList)
{
    if(item.key == "unRead")
    {
        foreach(var subItem in item.value) // evt do a List<string> temp = item.value first
        {
            foreach(var compItem in compareList)
            {
                if(compItem == subItem) resList.Add(compItem);
            }
        }
        item.remove(); // I actualy wanted to change from unRead to read, but I figured I could just remove it from the list.
    }
}
```

This should be able to be faste if I use Threads and go through each list in seperat threads, evt with a max thread amount of 10 or something.
So what I tryed was doing this.

```
foreach(var item in mainList)
{
    Thread myThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        if(item.key == "unRead")
        {
            foreach(var subItem in item.value) // evt do a List<string> temp = item.value first
            {
                foreach(var compItem in compareList)
                {
                    if(compItem == subItem) resList.Add(compItem);
                }
            }
            item.remove(); // I actualy wanted to change from unRead to read, but I figured I could just remove it from the list.
        }
    });
    myThread.start();
}
```

But this dident give any expected output at all...

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you please specify, what exactly the expected result looks like, and what the current outcome is?

Comment: or is it just about speeding things up?

Comment: `resList` should be locked, because it is modified in multiple threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resList` should be locked, because it is modified in multiple threads. Also you need to wait until all threads are done. You should use `Parallel.Foreach()` for this.

For example:

```
Parallel.Foreach(mainList, (item) =>
{
    if(item.key == "unRead")
    {
        foreach(var subItem in item.value) // evt do a List<string> temp = item.value first
        {
            foreach(var compItem in compareList)
            {
                if(compItem == subItem) 
                    lock(resList)
                        resList.Add(compItem);
            }
        }
    }
});

mainList.RemoveAll(item => item.key == "unRead");
```

---

This can be shorted with some linq-magic:

```
Parallel.Foreach(mainList, (item) =>
{
    if(item.key == "unRead")
    {
        foreach(var subItem in item.value) // evt do a List<string> temp = item.value first
        {
            if(compareList.Contains(subItem))
                lock(resList)
                    resList.Add(compItem);
        }
    }
});
```

---

And without threading/locking:

```
var resList = mainList.Where(item => item.key == "unRead")
                      .SelectMany(subitem => compareList.Contains(subitem))).ToList();
```

It would be usefull to use a `HashSet<>` instead of a `List<>` for the `compareList`

Comment: You can find common with this logic List<string> duplicates = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

As Jerone van Langen pointed out, already, the problem is that the access to the list is causing a race condition. You can either resolve this by introducing locks, or you could use a collection implementation that is thread-safe. The latter approach includes classes that work lock-free, which may give you better performance results. For example, you may take a look at `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`.

Either way, the first optimization would definitely be to use hash sets for the comparison list, at least if you expect these lists to contain more than 10 elements (otherwise, a list is probably faster).